# Put forms.DateField parameter into view method

Tags: python, django, fedora-commons

I have following problem:

In my forms.py i have following line in class:

```
date_from = forms.DateField(label='date', initial='1800-01-01', widget=SelectDateWidget(years=[y for y in range(1450,2050)]))
```

In template i can choose the concrete date. 
This parameter i want to transfer to my view.py file to the following method:

```
def adv_search(request):
    objects = None
    if request.GET.get('key'):
        form = AdvancedSearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            repo = Repository()
            objects = list(repo.find_objects(date__gt='2012-07-23'))                            
        return render(request, 'templates/adv_search.html', {'form': form, 'objects': objects })
    return render(request, 'templates/adv_search.html', {'form': AdvancedSearchForm(), 'objects': objects})
```

In `objects = list(repo.find_objects(date__gt='2012-07-23'))` i have `date__gt` with concrete Date.

How i can add to `date__gt` the date from `form.Date.Field` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's in [`form.cleaned_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form):

You can access it by doing:

```
objects = list(repo.find_objects(date__gt=form.cleaned_data['date_from']))
```

This is assuming that your form declaration looks something like:

```
class AdvancedSearchForm(forms.Form):
    date_from = forms.DateField(...) 
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for a fast answer. After adding the code i reiceive the following mistake: "TypeError: argument of type 'datetime.date' is not iterable"

Comment: @andy_bu That's probably an issue with the code from `find_objects` - can you post that code?

Comment: I use Eulfedora bibliothek. find_objects is one of methods. Hier is the code: `code`def find_objects(self, terms=None, type=None, chunksize=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Find objects in Fedora.  Find query should be generated via keyword
    args, based on the fields in Fedora documentation.  By default, the
    query uses a contains (~) search for all search terms.  Calls
    :meth:`ApiFacade.findObjects`. Results seem to return consistently
    in ascending PID order.
    repository.find_objects(date__gt='20010302')
    `code`     I can't put all method in comment, to long.

Comment: If i call objects = list(repo.find_objects(date__gt='2010-01-01')) i receive a list of objects, that have date older than '2010-01-01'. Of course i want to choose the date from the web site. I added DateField to my form and added it to my template. But it does't work.

Comment: I solve the problem. I have datetime.date and i need to convert it to string -  objects = list(repo.find_objects(date__gt=str(form.cleaned_data['date_from'])))